# layoutAttributesForElementsInRect is returning rect size bigger than content size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, contentsize

[`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:) is returning me a *rect* with a size of `{1024, 2048}` (w, h), but [`collectionViewContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/collectionViewContentSize) is `{1408, 1210}` (w, h). I'm using the iPad 2 iOS 8.4 simulator.

How can the rectangle with the target views be bigger than the content size?

My goal is to calculate the `NSIndexPath` out from *rect*. Should I limit it to the real content size? Or am I setting a wrong size here?